# Extending vs not extending a class in PHP

Tags: php, inheritance

I'm new. Below is the beginning of an attempt to interface with a database. Please let me know if the syntax is not correct, it seems to work on my localhost.

I think I could have typed class `Database extends Mysqli`, right? which would then have made the methods of Mysqli directly accessible to Database rather than through an instance created in the class itself. Would that have been preferable to what I have done?

```
class Database {

    #The variable that stores the database handle
    public $db;

    #The Database objects's datbase parameters
    public $host;
    public $user;
    public $password;
    public $database;

    #creates a Database object with the required databases details
    public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $database) {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    #Stores the database handle as a var $db of the Database instance 
    public function connect() {
        if ($this->db = new Mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database)) {
            if ($this->db->connect_errno) {
                echo "No connection could be made <br/>";
            } else {
                echo "database succesfully connected <br/>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `class Database` represents the database handle, then it should not have it public:

```
#The variable that stores the database handle
public $db;
```

Otherwise you would not encapsulate that detail and therefore you wouldn't need your class at all.

Next to that, when you start to write classes, `echo` does not belong in there:

```
    if ($this->db = new Mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database)) {
        if ($this->db->connect_errno) {
            echo "No connection could be made <br/>";
        } else {
            echo "database succesfully connected <br/>";
        }
    }
```

Because classes consists of methods returning via their return value *and not* via standard output. Instead you want to throw an exception here. Which is also a feature of Mysqli already, therefore, you don't need to write that error handling code your own to get started:

- [Turning query errors to Exceptions in MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14578243/367456)

After getting these more or less obvious ones out of the way, you're asking yourself whether or not you should inherit `mysqli` instead of aggregating it.

I actually can not tell you. So far the code you've shared just shows standard functionality of a `mysqli` therefore I would suggest to drop that class completely as the code looks superfluous. So I would say: neither. I see no reason for your `Database` class as you just could use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/class.mysqli) instead.